# Create chart showing monthly sum from daily entry custom list

Tags: list-view, custom-list, chart-web-part

I have a custom list of about 200 entries, which has three columns (name, mm/dd/yy, $amount). I would like to be able to view a summary of the total amount by month, either in a Chart web part or a custom view, but I can't seem to be able to.

```
    A, 01/01/12, $50
    B, 01/07/12, $50
    C, 01/21/12, $50
    D, 02/01/12, $50
    E, 02/02/12, $50
    F, 02/03/12, $50
```

This would yield a bar chart with two columns [Jan $150] and [Feb $150]

Can anyone suggest a method please?

Thanks.